# ReadLine(); between values

Tags: c#, readline, dice

I made a dice game and just a few moments ago asked for a solution here, which i got. it made a new problem and in which i cant seem to find a answer.

Heres the code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Noppapeli
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int pyöräytys;
            int satunnainen;
            int luku = 0;

            Random noppa = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);

            Console.WriteLine("Anna arvaus");
            int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(),out pyöräytys);

            Console.WriteLine("Haettava numero on: " + pyöräytys);
            Console.ReadLine();
            do
            {
                luku++;
                satunnainen = noppa.Next(1, 7);
                Console.WriteLine("numero on: " + satunnainen);
                if (satunnainen == pyöräytys)
                {
                    satunnainen = pyöräytys;
                }
            } while (pyöräytys != satunnainen);

            Console.WriteLine("^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^");
            Console.WriteLine("Haettu numero: " + pyöräytys);
            Console.WriteLine("Pyöräytetty numero: " + satunnainen);
            Console.Write("Kesti " + luku + " Nopan pyöräytystä saada tulos!");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that `int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(),out pyöräytys);` needs to only take values between 1-6. now if I put a 7 in there the game is on a loop to find a 7 from a D6.
Is there a easy solution or should i just make the dices bigger.

Comment: `var knäckebröd = 0; while (knäckebröd < 1 || knäckebröd > 6) { int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(),out knäckebröd); }` - don't accept "invalid" input and let the user input again until the input is in a valid range.

Comment: Why don't you just check that the parsed int from the Console.ReadLine() is between 1-6 or not? If it isn't show an error message, and ask for a new value.

Comment: The knäckerbröd AKA näkkäri worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to add some kind of loop to ensure the value is valid and continue looping until a valid value is provided.

```
pyöräytys = -1; // Set to invalid to trigger loop

while (pyöräytys < 1 || pyöräytys > 6)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Anna arvaus");
   int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(),out pyöräytys);

   if (pyöräytys < 1 || pyöräytys > 6)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Invalid value, must be 1-6"); // Error message
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just verify the input value is between 1 and 6:

```
bool valid;
while (!valid)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Anna arvaus");
    int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(),out pyöräytys);
    valid = (pyöräytys > 0 && pyöräytys <= 6);
}
```

Comment: `pyöräytys` needs to be 1 to 6. In your example, `0` would be acceptable.  Perhaps change check to `pyöräytys > 0` ?

Comment: Should be >= 1 since the random is between 1 and 6. Entering 0 will cause the same issue